# What does proxy in yum repo do?

Tags: centos6, yum

Referring to http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/yum/sn-yum-proxy-server.html,

What does the option do? Can it substitute the base URL by providing a local URL instead? That way I can access a local repo instead of the one in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

the baseurl is the actual url for your repo. If this Repo is hosted on internet where you need to go via proxy, then you need to specify the proxy setting as mentioned in the that you referred.

If you have a local repo which can be accessed without proxy, the no need to specify the proxy variable at all. Instead, specify the local repo url to base url and it should be working.